# CSS: Absolutely positioned pseudo element loses z-index?

Tags: css

Why would an absolutely positioned pseudo element be losing its `z-index` when using `transition`?

**The fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/jNgLL/

**What's happening?**
When you click on the `li`, it slides to the left without changing any `z-index` values. However, the `:after` content is popping up on top of the `li`.

**What should happen?**
I was hoping it would stay hidden behind the `li`.

**The CSS (simplified a little bit, see fiddle for full example):**

```
li {
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

li.active {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
}

li:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "Yada yada";
}
```

Why is the `:after` content not staying behind the `li`?

Comment: I don't see this in Chrome

Comment: [jsfiddle for Firefox (and non webkit browsers)](http://jsfiddle.net/jNgLL/1/)

Comment: I'm seeing this on Chrome 30.0.1599.101 (edit: and 31.0.1650.57).

Comment: +1 simply for having a very well formatted question

Comment: Still valid in Firefox 54 and Chrome 59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this on w3.org, which I think explains it: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#effects

> Any value other than ‘none’ for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

As I understand it, your `li:after` pseudo-element is inside the stacking context of the `li.active` element, and therefore cannot appear behind it.

Comment: I had a simpler case: a static container with an absolute content to be animated. I solved the issue paying attention to apply the transition only to the content and not to content+container. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 5):

@BernzSed's answer is correct. Here's a solution, though:

Wrap the content inside the `<li>` using a `<div>` (or any other element) with `position: relative`, then the `z-index: -1` on the psuedo element will force it to be behind the child element.

Here's the essential code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li><div>This is the first item</div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li,
li div {
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/jNgLL/3/

Also interesting to note: If you use a `:before` psuedo element, you don't need the `z-index: -1` because it's already falling under the `position: relative` child element in the stacking order.

Comment: I wish I could accept 2 answers. BernzSed is technically correct, but your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. BernzSed answered the question, I just got intrigued by solving the problem ;)